# GPO WMI filter on IP on RDS session

Tags: wmi, remote-desktop, gpo

With WMI filter on GPO, we can target specific IP range for example. But how can I target user's computer IP into a RDS user session?

Indeed, if I use WMI request like that

```
Select * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable WHERE (Mask='255.255.255.255' AND (Destination Like '10.10.10.%'))
```

IP is that of the session, i.e. of the RDS host, not that of the user's computer.

So, is there a WMI request or anything else I can use to target this IP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You still here? I think I found a solution, at least for my problem which was:

I want to apply firewall rules per GPO to block traffic to and from a network drive which contains sensitive data. This drive should be accessible if someone is connected by RDP via a trusted channel (which is identified by IP). If someone is connected by RDP via a untrusted channel (identified by different IP), the firewall rule to block the traffic should be deployed.

The query you are looking for is something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM msft_nettcpconnection where (remoteaddress like '10.%' AND LocalPort = '3389')"
```

The namespace in the WMI filter must be set to:

```
"ROOT\StandardCIMV2"
```

This filter returns a dataset if a TCP/IP connection from any 10.ish IP on port 3389 is established. When a dataset is returned the filter becomes active and the rule is deployed.

The statement itself isn't tricky. The trick was to find a class which can be queried that contains information about the RDP connection.

A PowerShell script to verify the query is:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace "ROOT\StandardCIMV2" -query "SELECT * FROM msft_nettcpconnection where (remoteaddress like '10.%' AND LocalPort = '3389')"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my case. And, by the way, the result surprises me because it doesn't match any IP range I would find. For the current test, I'm at home and "RemoteAddress" field not gives me an IP in a range that is absolutely not mine (that's a range we use for a VPN appliance) and my IP doesn't appear anywhere in the wmiobject.

Comment: Well, maybe this is related to my detailed setup. Im connecting via RDP to VMs running on a server. In the first place I'm connecting to a firewall via VPN. Either from where I'm connecting I got routed into different subnets. And from this subnet I'm RDPing to the VM. And in this VM I see either the one subnet, or the other subnet as TCP connection on the RDP port.